# Codeigniter image uploading not working in first attempt?

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I'm trying to create a image upload function for my e-commerce website. This is the function I used to upload files,

**Image upload function**

```
private function upload_product_image($name, $file) {

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $dir = $name;

    if (!is_dir('store/' . $dir)) {
        mkdir('store/' . $dir, 777, true);
    }

    $config['upload_path'] = './store/' . $dir . '/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name']   = TRUE;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file)) {
        return null;
    } else {
        if (is_file($config['upload_path'])) {
            chmod($config['upload_path'], 777);
        }

        $ud = $this->upload->data();

        $source = $ud['full_path'];
        $destination = $ud['full_path'];

        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        imagejpeg($image, $destination, 75);

        return $config['upload_path'] . $ud['file_name'];
    }
}
```

**Save product**

```
public function save_product(){

    *** other code ****
    $dir = date('Ymdhis');

    $dir = url_title($dir, 'dash', true);

    $this->upload_product_image($dir, 'add-product-image1'),

    *** other code ****
}
```

There are couple of issues when running this function,

1. Image is not uploaded in first attempt ( Add new product )
2. But It created the product folder
3. If I update the product images It is working fine.

If you could show me, what is the wrong with this code It'll be really helpful.

Thank you so much

Comment: You are passing string instead of actual file that will be in $_FILES global. That is why image is not uploading.Please check the errors returned by $this->upload->do_upload() as well.It will give you more idea

Comment: Add this line `if( !empty($_FILES['add-product-image1'])){ $this->upload_product_image($dir, 'add-product-image1')}`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that

Comment: @DevangNaghera that is what `do_upload` expects, the name of the file upload field

Comment: @Artier why would checking if the file array exists benefit op? The only time that should be done is on update so as to not remove the (previously) inserted image but that is exactly when the error is occuring "first attempt". @Malinda, instead of returning null please enter `echo $this->upload->display_errors()` and try to replicate the problem again to get the error. I don't see anything strikingly wrong with your code, so it would help to know whats happening.